# Which class invoked my static method?

Tags: java, reflection

Suppose that I have a Java class with a static method, like so:

```
class A
{
    static void foo()
    {
        // Which class invoked me?
    }
}
```

And suppose further that class A has an arbitrary number of subclasses:

```
class B extends A { }
class C extends A { }
class D extends A { }
...
```

Now consider the following method invocations:

```
A.foo();
B.foo();
C.foo();
D.foo();
...
```

My question is, how can method `foo()` tell which class is invoking it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can't, and that's part of the problem with static methods.  As far as the compiler is concerned `A.foo()` and `B.foo()` are exactly the same thing.  In fact, they compile down to the same bytecode.  You can't get more similar than that.

If you really need this sort of information, use a singleton and turn `foo()` into an instance method.  If you still like the static syntax, you can build a facade `A.foo()`.

Answer (score 4):

Although you can't find out which class the static method was *invoked on*, it is possible to find out which class actually *invoked* the method at runtime:

```
static void foo()
{
   Throwable t = new Throwable();
   StackTraceElement[] trace = t.getStackTrace();
   String className = trace[1].getClassName();
   Class whoCalledMe = null;
   try
   {
      whoCalledMe = Class.forName( className );
   }
   catch( Exception e )
   {
   }
}
```

I'm not saying that this is good practice and its probably not great from a performance perspective either, but it should work. Don't know if that helps you any ...

Comment: Yuck. It works; but IIRC reflection was deliberately made ugly to discourage these sorts of things.

Comment: I was looking for a way to write a static utility method `trace(String s)` such that, if a method in class Foo invoked `trace("hi")`, it would write to SYSOUT: **Foo: hi**.  This appears to do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

```
class A
{
    static void foo(A whoIsCalingMe)
    {
        // Which class invoked me?
    }
}
```